# Not able to find IIS Manager and enable IIS in Windows7 Home Basic

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IIS Management Console not found in Windows 7 Home Basic](https://superuser.com/questions/161013/iis-management-console-not-found-in-windows-7-home-basic)

I enabled IIS services in the add/remove windows components. However, when i want to open the manager, the IIS Manager does not appear under the administrative tools on the control panel. If i type the shortcut "inetmgr" into the run block it doesn't find it. However, i know the service installed correctly. It is a very frustrating problem since everyone says find it here or here but no one gives any help on what to do if is doesn't appear in the said locations at all. Can anyone please help me?
The system i am using is Windows 7 home basic.
The service installed correctly but i cannot find the IIS Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately IIS Manager isn't available in Home Basic. You can use [AppCmd](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe), although it's a bit more limited.